# can global variables be accessed and modified in various classes in C++

Tags: c++, global-variables, extern

I have run into code spaghetti where i need to instrument flow control i.e., send data one at a time. How can i use global variable to solve this? If global variables don't work, what is the way to access and modify variables in multiples functions which could be in different classes

I tried the following (I am pasting partial code) but it gave me ld error that I could not resolve. I want to ask what might be the best and clean approach to solve this.

**file1.h**

```
int data_received; //global variable
class abc
{
.
.
.
public:
  void send_data(..)
.
.
.
};
```

**file1.c**

```
void send_data()
{
  while(!end_of_file)
  {
    read_line;
    data_received = 0;
    transmit_data(line);
    while(data_received == 0)
      cout<<"waiting for response before proceeding\n";

  }

}
```

**file2.c**

```
//data receive class

void transmit_data()
{
 ....
 ....
 ....
//data sent upstream
 data_received = 1;
}
```

I have searched many posts on stackoverflow but there is no clear answer. Some suggest to use extern variable but no clear example of external variable being modified in more than one class functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please learn more about

- `Declare` vs `Define` in C and C++.
- `compile` vs `link`

`define` global variable

```
// file1.cpp
int data_received;
```

`extern` tell complier that `data_received` can be found when linker.

```
// file2.cpp
extern int data_received;
```

in addition, `static` can limit `my_global_var` only to be used in file defining it. example

```
// file3.cpp
static int my_global_var = 1;
```

Error will be occured in `linker`

```
// file4.cpp
extern int my_global_var;
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you use class_name::my_global_var to access this static variable in another class's function? Do you need to #include the class or not?

Comment: you can access `static member` in other file/function. Please learn static keyword in c++. Certainly, `#include` is necessary (compile step, you must tell compile where is it).

Comment: @user2979872 Learn more about different  `compile` and `link` futher. It will help you.

Comment: Please give me a short explanation here and point to a good tutorial I could follow

Comment: `compile` will make our code conver to machine instructions, but, the `compile unit` is not all soure codes (file1.cpp and file2.cpp are in different compile unit usually), please google it. `link` will merge all `compile unit` in together. In this step, some variable in other unit can be found, just as global variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark that `extern` in the header file and then define it **once**, either in `file1.c` or `file2.c`

For example

**file1.h**

```
extern int data_received;
```

**file1.c**

```
// initialize it 
int data_received = 0;
```

**file2.c**

```
// either do this if the include is logically needed
#include "file1.h"
// or 
extern int data_received;

// then use it normally
void foo() {
    cout << data_received << endl;
}
```

Or if this is C++ you can declare that variable as a `static` variable in the class, define it in the `.cpp` file and then use it like a normal variable but prefixed with the scope resolution for the class.  For example

```
class Something {
public:
    static int data_received = 0;
};

void foo() {
    cout << Something::data_received << endl;
}
```

Comment: As i wrote. I need to modify the variable inside a function in another class. I can't use extern inside function. If you think so, please post your code

Comment: how can I go to the next iteration of the while loop with your code?

Comment: @user2979872 as you would normally, the variable is just a global variable

Comment: do you think it will compile if i put data_received = 1 inside foo() function?

Comment: @user2979872 yes, with either of the schemes I have outlined above it will work

Comment: please correct me if i am wrong. I saw another stackoverflow post stating static variables can only be used where they are defined meaning not in another class function in a different file

Comment: @user2979872 static class variables and the extern variable trick are both almost essentially the same thing in the case above.  Either will work

Answer (score 1):

By having your global variable deined in the header file, you will create a copy of it in any 'c' file which it includes. There far the ld will complain. 
You need to declare it as 'extern' in the header file an then define it in a single 'c' file.

file1.h

```
extern int data_received;
```

file1.c

```
#include <file1.h>
int data_received = 0;
```

file2.c

```
#include <file1.h>
```

This way you would only define one copy of it and make it known to all files which include the header file.

Comment: if you do as 'curious' suggested,  you do not need to declare it as 'extern' in the header file. You still have one copy of the variable defined in file1.c an just making file2.c aware of it. Both solution are correct. your choice.